# BHO: c2259 cannot instantiate abstract class

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm trying to build BHO, but the compiler says:

> Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\Vc7\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h(1759):
>
> error C2259: 'ATL::CComObject' : cannot instantiate abstract
>
> class
>
> ```
>     with
>     [
>         Base=CSample
>     ]
> ```

How to resolve this error ?
I know I'm using old VS but I need it now.

**code:**

```
#ifndef __Sample_H_
#define __Sample_H_

#include "resource.h"      
#include "ExDisp.h"
//#include <shlguid.h>
//#include <mshtml.h>

#include "BhoPlugin.h"
#include "ExDispID.h"
#include "mshtml.h"
#include "wininet.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

class ATL_NO_VTABLE CSample : 
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CSample, &CLSID_Sample>,
    public IObjectWithSiteImpl<CSample>,
    public IDispatchImpl<ISample, &IID_ISample, &LIBID_BHOPLUGINLib>,
    public IOleCommandTarget
{
public:
    CSample()
    {
    }

DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_Sample)

DECLARE_PROTECT_FINAL_CONSTRUCT()
BEGIN_COM_MAP(CSample)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(ISample)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IObjectWithSite)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IOleCommandTarget)
END_COM_MAP()

public:
    CComQIPtr<IWebBrowser2, &IID_IWebBrowser2> mWebBrowser2;

    HRESULT RegisterEventHandler(BOOL inAdvise);
    STDMETHOD(Invoke)(DISPID dispidMember,REFIID riid, LCID lcid, WORD wFlags,
                     DISPPARAMS * pDispParams, VARIANT * pvarResult,
                     EXCEPINFO * pexcepinfo, UINT * puArgErr);

        STDMETHOD(SetSite)(IUnknown *pUnkSite);

        STDMETHOD(Exec)(const GUID *pguidCmdGroup, DWORD nCmdID, 
        DWORD nCmdExecOpt, VARIANTARG *pvaIn, VARIANTARG *pvaOut);


private:
    CComPtr<IWebBrowser2> m_spWebBrowser;
    CComQIPtr<IOleCommandTarget, 
        &IID_IOleCommandTarget> m_spTarget;

};


#endif
```

Comment: Looks like `CSample` is missing some pure virtual method implementations ...

Comment: please tell me which ones,  i can add then and test and i will accept your answer if it helps

Comment: @ManY Your compiler errors should tell you that.

Comment: For helpful tips check [this](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?444271-ATL-error-C2259-ATL-CComObject-cannot-instantiate-abstract-class)